# iMessage off, deregistered, still cannot receive SMS

Tags: messages

I am trying to turn iMessage off on an iPhone. I tried repeatedly all the steps here http://www.cnet.com/how-to/three-steps-to-disable-imessage-and-not-lose-your-mind/ or here
http://www.ianswerguy.com/not-receiving-text-messages-from-iphone-users/
without any success:

1. Turned iMessage off on all devices.
2. Logged off iTunes and iCloud on my iPhone - for extra sanity
3. Turned iMessage and FaceTime off on my iPhone.

No success. I am able to send SMS (green messages), while the other's iPhones still see me as blue. If they send the message, I never get it, until I turn iMessage back on.

4. I also deregistered my number on Apple's web site. No success. When I tried to do it again, it told me "I reached the maximum number of tries".

This is an iPhone 5s. I tried the same experiment on another iPhone and it worked fine. It looks like it is something particular about this number, Apple will just not remove it off the iMessage server. The only thing that's different is that it is a prepaid, no-data SIM, but I do not see what that would make a difference. (It is hard to replicate it though, as it is a very rare configuration)

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: SMS to and from other than iPhones works fine.

Comment: What does your carrier tech support say? They have control over the modems that connect to your device and can look at the logs and what data your phone sends back. They should be able to trace an outgoing SMS and tell you where it was delivered if you ask nicely.

Comment: That's very good to know. Did not think this was possible. Will contact them if Apple is not helpful.